# GWT SerializationException for java.util.Date

Tags: date, jpa, tomcat, serialization, gwt

Sorry, I couldn't find any solution on the web.

Here is project properties:

**GWT:** 2.5.1

**GXT:** 3.0.1

**EclipseLink:** JPA 2.1

**JDK:** 1.8.0_221

**Tomcat:** 9.0

**MySQL Connector Java:** 8.0.17

**NetBeans:** 11.1

And here is the Tomcat log:

```
14-Sep-2019 22:53:56.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
14-Sep-2019 22:53:56.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
14-Sep-2019 22:53:56.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@6dd729')
14-Sep-2019 22:53:56.472 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('javax.faces.validator.beanValidator.ValidatorFactory', 'org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder$OpenEJBValidatorFactory@51cbd1d')
14-Sep-2019 22:54:52.413 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
    **com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = Sun Feb 25 12:00:00 EET 2018**
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:757)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:796)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:669)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:44)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:39)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:51)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:28)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:788)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:669)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:757)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:796)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:769)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:796)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:669)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:471)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:563)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Here is the DTA code:

```java
package tr.edu.asbu.basvuru.shared.model;

import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.ValueProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.ModelKeyProvider;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.PropertyAccess;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author g.ersoy
 */
public class ProgramlarModel implements Serializable {

    public interface DataPropertyAccess extends PropertyAccess<ProgramlarModel> {

        ModelKeyProvider<ProgramlarModel> pkId();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> kodu();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> adi();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> turu();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, Date> basTar();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, Date> bitTar();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, Date> basvuruIlkTarih();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, Date> basvuruSonTarih();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, Integer> ucret();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> aciklama();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> durum();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> basvur();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> detayUrl();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> basvuruDurumu();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, Double> puan();

        ValueProvider<ProgramlarModel, String> sinavSonucu();

    }

    Integer pkId;
    String kodu;
    String adi;
    String turu;
    Date basTar;
    Date bitTar;
    Date basvuruIlkTarih;
    Date basvuruSonTarih;
    Integer ucret;
    String aciklama;
    String durum;
    String basvur;
    String detayUrl;
    String basvuruDurumu;
    Double puan;
    String sinavSonucu;

    public ProgramlarModel() {
    }

    public ProgramlarModel(Integer pkId, String kodu, String adi, String turu, Date basTar, Date bitTar, Date basvuruIlkTarih, Date basvuruSonTarih, Integer ucret, String aciklama, String durum, String basvur, String detayUrl) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
        this.kodu = kodu;
        this.adi = adi;
        this.turu = turu;
        this.basTar = basTar;
        this.bitTar = bitTar;
        this.basvuruIlkTarih = basvuruIlkTarih;
        this.basvuruSonTarih = basvuruSonTarih;
        this.ucret = ucret;
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
        this.durum = durum;
        this.basvur = basvur;
        this.detayUrl = detayUrl;
    }

    public Integer getPkId() {
        return pkId;
    }

    public void setPkId(Integer pkId) {
        this.pkId = pkId;
    }

    public String getKodu() {
        return kodu;
    }

    public void setKodu(String kodu) {
        this.kodu = kodu;
    }

    public String getAdi() {
        return adi;
    }

    public void setAdi(String adi) {
        this.adi = adi;
    }

    public String getTuru() {
        return turu;
    }

    public void setTuru(String turu) {
        this.turu = turu;
    }

    public Date getBasTar() {
        return basTar;
    }

    public void setBasTar(Date basTar) {
        this.basTar = basTar;
    }

    public Date getBitTar() {
        return bitTar;
    }

    public void setBitTar(Date bitTar) {
        this.bitTar = bitTar;
    }

    public Date getBasvuruIlkTarih() {
        return basvuruIlkTarih;
    }

    public void setBasvuruIlkTarih(Date basvuruIlkTarih) {
        this.basvuruIlkTarih = basvuruIlkTarih;
    }

    public Date getBasvuruSonTarih() {
        return basvuruSonTarih;
    }

    public void setBasvuruSonTarih(Date basvuruSonTarih) {
        this.basvuruSonTarih = basvuruSonTarih;
    }

    public Integer getUcret() {
        return ucret;
    }

    public void setUcret(Integer ucret) {
        this.ucret = ucret;
    }

    public String getAciklama() {
        return aciklama;
    }

    public void setAciklama(String aciklama) {
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
    }

    public String getDurum() {
        return durum;
    }

    public void setDurum(String durum) {
        this.durum = durum;
    }

    public String getBasvur() {
        return basvur;
    }

    public void setBasvur(String basvur) {
        this.basvur = basvur;
    }

    public String getDetayUrl() {
        return detayUrl;
    }

    public void setDetayUrl(String detayUrl) {
        this.detayUrl = detayUrl;
    }

    public String getBasvuruDurumu() {
        return basvuruDurumu;
    }

    public void setBasvuruDurumu(String basvuruDurumu) {
        this.basvuruDurumu = basvuruDurumu;
    }

    public Double getPuan() {
        return puan;
    }

    public void setPuan(Double puan) {
        this.puan = puan;
    }

    public String getSinavSonucu() {
        return sinavSonucu;
    }

    public void setSinavSonucu(String sinavSonucu) {
        this.sinavSonucu = sinavSonucu;
    }

}
```

Here is the server side code that returning DTA list. The exception is thrown at the last line.

```java
@Override
    public PagingLoadResult<ProgramlarModel> getProgramlarOfUserWithFilter(Integer userPk, FilterPagingLoadConfig config) {
        List<ProgramlarModel> models = new ArrayList<ProgramlarModel>();
        List<Programlar> entities = programlarFacade.findAll();
        for (Programlar e : entities) {
            ProgramlarModel m = new ProgramlarModel(e.getPkId(), e.getKodu(), e.getAdi(), e.getTuru(), e.getBasTar(), e.getBitTar(), e.getBasvuruIlkTarih(), e.getBasvuruSonTarih(), e.getUcret(), e.getAciklama(), null, null, e.getDetayUrl());
            Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            if (now.before(e.getBasvuruIlkTarih())) {
                m.setDurum("FUTURE");
            } else if (now.after(e.getBasvuruSonTarih())) {
                m.setDurum("PAST");
            } else {
                m.setDurum("NOW");
            }

            m.setBasvuruDurumu("");
            Basvurular b = basvurularFacade.findByUserFkAndProgramFk(userPk, e.getPkId());
            if (b != null) {
                m.setBasvuruDurumu(b.getBasvuruDurumu() == null ? "" : b.getBasvuruDurumu());
                if (b.getSonucFk() != null) {
                    SinavSonuc s = sinavSonucFacade.find(b.getSonucFk());
                    m.setPuan(s.getPuan());
                    m.setSinavSonucu(s.getSonuc());
                }
            }

            if (isCorrectModel(config, m)) {
                models.add(m);
            }
        }
        List<ProgramlarModel> filteredModels = applySort(config, models);//sonra sort
        List<ProgramlarModel> sublist = applyPaging(config, filteredModels);//en son da paging
        return new PagingLoadResultBean<>(sublist, filteredModels.size(), config.getOffset());
    }
```

Comment: Check your imports. `java.util.Date` is not the same as `org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy`.

Comment: sorry, but I have never used any org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date import anywhere. :(

Comment: JPA is replacing your `java.util.Date` with `org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$Date$proxy` for some reason, and that isn't the type you told GWT you were going to serialize, so it is failing. I'm not a JPA expert, (tag this with JPA perhaps?), but I think you'll need to detach() the entity so that the properties aren't wired up to magically write back to the DB.

Comment: Same discussion here http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/OpenJPA-Date-Proxy-serialization-problem-when-using-entities-with-GWT-td6156425.html

Comment: I couldn't solve it yet. :(((

It is very important for me.